# Memory management in the composite pattern

Tags: c++, memory-management, graph, factory, composite

I am encountering the same problem over and over, in the last weeks. Boiled down to its core, I build a (directed acyclic) hierarchy of objects like:

- `a -> c`
- `b -> c`
- `b -> d`

An instance can have more than one parent, and more than one child. `c` might be a value shared among readers and writers. `b` might be a composite value. The hierarchy is easily created by a factory - e.g. `a.setChild(new C())`. Later, a client only cares about the root, on which she calls `getValue()` or `setValue()`.

My question is: Who cleans up the hierarchy? Who is responsible to call `delete` on `b` or `c`?

1. **Option - The factory created the nodes, the factory must delete the nodes:**
   I do not like this option, because I understand a factory as a replacement for `new`. It feels weird to keep a factory until the instances it created can be destroyed.
2. **Option - "Smart" pointers:**
   Much less good, because it pollutes the interface, and introduces a lot of complexity for a simple thing such as pointers.
3. **Option - A graph-like class that does the memory management:**
   The class collects all nodes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, ... and provides access to the root. The nodes themselves reference each other, but do not delete children, or parents. If the "graph" or composite manager is destroyed, it destroys all nodes.

I prefer the last option. It, however, complicates the construction of the hierarchy. Either you build the hierarchy outside, and tell the graph about every single node, or you build the hierarchy inside the graph, which smells like option 1. The graph can only delete, what it knows. Therefore, memory leaks are somehow in the design, if you have to pass the nodes to the graph.

Is there a pattern for this problem? Which strategy do you prefer?

**Edit 1 - Sep 1st, 2014:** Sorry, for being unspecific with respect to smart pointers. I tried to avoid yet another "when to use smart pointers question", and instead focus the question on alternative solutions. However, I am willing to use smart pointers, if they indeed are the best option (or if necessary).

In my opinion, the signature `setChild(C* child)` should be preferred over `setChild(std::shared_ptr<C> child)` for the same reason as for-each loops should be preferred over iterators. However, I must admit that like `std:string` a shared pointer is more specific about its semantic.

In terms of complexity, every operation inside a node, now, have to deal with shared pointers. `std::vector<C*>` becomes `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<C> >`, ... Furthermore, every pointer carries a reference count around, which could be avoided if there were other options.

I should add that I develop a low level part of a real-time system. It is not a firmware but close.

**Edit 2 - Sep 1st, 2014:**
Thank you for all the input. My specific problem is: I get a byte array with lets say sensor data. At some point, I am told which value is written where in that array. On the one hand, I want to have a mapping from a position in the array to a primitive value (int32, double, ...). On the other hand, I want to merge primitive values to complex types (structures, vectors, ...). Unfortunately, not all mappings are bidirectional. Eg. I can read a comparison between values, but I can not write values according to the comparison result. Therefore, I separated readers and writers and let them, if necessary, access the same value.

Comment: Why do smart pointers pollute the interface and introduce complexity??

Comment: "it pollutes the interface" Show an example.

Comment: If "the client only cares about the root", then the smart pointers won't be exposed in the interface, whether or not you regard such exposure as "pollution". Or are you referring to the interface for building the graph? In that case, I'd regard smart pointers as quite the opposite of pollution, since they unambiguously specify the ownership model.

Comment: `parent.setChild(C* child)` should not be preferred if the parent should own the child. A shared_ptr or unique_ptr would be preferred.

Comment: What is the lifetime of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`? Are they independent? Or will they all die at the same time?

Comment: Sometimes when you have a hierarchy which allows multiple parents, it indicates a potential design error. Smart pointers (which are great) may solve your memory management problem, but you may have a logical problem underneath.

Comment: Without knowing more specifics about the problem I would go with the graph object you call to create the objects and link them outside the graph. Graph object holds the ownership to the nodes. It's simple and you can manage manage transparently how the memory for nodes is managed (e.g. you could put them in a vector for example for compact memory usage)

Comment: @ChrisDrew They will die at the same time. The complete hierarchy is thrown away, if the communication is finished. Maybe they are independent in the sense that a writer root is destroyed before a reader root (which access the same value). But if a writer is destroyed, a reader will follow in the same destructor.

Comment: @JarkkoL I added details about my specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Option - "Smart" pointers: Much less good, because it pollutes the
>   interface, and introduces a lot of complexity for a simple thing such
>   as pointers.

Smart pointers are pointers with memory management, which is exactly what you need.

You are not forced to expose the smart pointers in your interface, you can get a raw pointer from the smart one as long as the object is still owned by a smart pointer somewhere (Note that this is not necessarily the best idea though, smart pointers in an interface is far from being an ugly thing).

Actually exposing raw pointers in your interface indirectly introduce much more pollution and complexity because you need to document ownership and lifetime rules which are explicit when using smart pointers, which makes them even more simpler to use than "simple pointers".

Also it is most likely the "futur" way of doing things: since c++11/14 smart pointers are part of the standard as much as `std::string`, would you say that `std::string` *pollutes the interface and introduces a lot of complexity* compared to a `const char*` ?

If you have performance issues, then the question is: will your hand crafted alternative solution be truly more performant (this need to be measured) and is it worth it in term of development time required to develop the feature and maintain the code ?

Comment: I would say `std::string` pollutes the interface and adds unnecessary overhead compared to `const char*` ;)

Comment: @JarkkoL I guess you would also consider that `c++` pollutes the interface and adds unnecessary overhead compared to `c` :)

Comment: depending on the case, yes. E.g. When using string instead when const char* suffices. I develop for memory constraint real-time systems where I can't throw away performance and memory like tictacs :)

Comment: @JarkkoL good point! I forgot to tell that the code is indeed a critical part of a real-time application. Drax, does this change the applicability of smart pointers, or should the compiler worry about that? (I am afraid that I am with JarkkoL on that point.)

Comment: I wouldn't call `std::string` "pollution", but it does make the interface completely unusable from other languages, or even code compiled with other C++ compilers.  So restraint is sometimes called for.